# How to configure AutoMapper with generic types

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

I am trying to implement propertywise version tracking in my entities. Using the schema of `TrackedProperty` for my trackable properties;

```
public class PropertyVersion<TValue, TVersion>
{
    public TVersion Version { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}


public class TrackedProperty<TValue, TVersion> : List<PropertyVersion<TValue, TVersion>>
{

}
```

For example, In my repository, I will keep the `TrackedFoo` object and I will be able to retrieve the data at a specific version (in this case the version is described as a Time object) in `Foo` from.

```
public class TrackedFoo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public TrackedProperty<string, DateTime> Name { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to keep things generic as much as possible. So I tried to use AutoMapper but I wasn't able to configure it in a generic way which I won't need to configure mapping of every single `TrackedTypeX` to `TypeX`.

*I need to get the last PropertyVersion item in TrackedProperty and map its Value property to a TValue type*

Can you please help me find a solution for this problem?

I can reduce the  number of variable types (is that what you call the stuff between <> ?, anyway) to single using

```
DateTrackedProperty<TValue> : TrackedProperty<TValue,DateTime>
IntegerTrackedProperty<TValue> : TrackedProperty<TValue, int>
StringTrackedProperty<TValue> : TrackedProperty<TValue, string>
```

I am ok with having to write AutoMapper configuration for these three types.

Comment: Ok, before speaking about generic mapping, what would be the concrete mapping from `TrackedFoo` to `Foo`? More specifically, how are you going to convert `TrackedProperty<string, DateTime>` to `string`?

Comment: @IvanStoev,  TrackedProperty<string,DateTime> has string Value property. So I just need to get that value no fancy conversion

Comment: Aha, why don't you show it then in the question? :)

Comment: @IvanStoev sorry. TrackedProperty<string,DateTime> doesn't have a Value property. It's actually list of PropertyVersion which hold the value property. I need to get the last PropertyVersion in TrackedProperty and use that one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the end I managed to create a generic mapping profile (only one way)
by placing the following in my MappingProfile

```
CreateMap(typeof(PropertyVersion<,>), typeof(object)).ConvertUsing(typeof(PropertyVersionToValueConverter<,>));
CreateMap(typeof(TrackedProperty<,>), typeof(PropertyVersion<,>)).ConvertUsing(typeof(TrackedPropertyToPropertyVersionConverter<,>));
CreateMap(typeof(TrackedProperty<,>), typeof(object)).ConvertUsing(typeof(TrackedPropertyToValueConverter<,>));
```

where

```
public class PropertyVersionToValueConverter<TValue, TVersion> : ITypeConverter<PropertyVersion<TValue, TVersion>, TValue>
{
    public TValue Convert(PropertyVersion<TValue, TVersion> source, TValue destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source != null)
            return source.Value;
        return default(TValue);
    }
}

public class TrackedPropertyToPropertyVersionConverter<TValue, TVersion> : ITypeConverter<TrackedProperty<TValue, TVersion>, PropertyVersion<TValue, TVersion>>
{
    public PropertyVersion<TValue, TVersion> Convert(TrackedProperty<TValue, TVersion> source, PropertyVersion<TValue, TVersion> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source != null && source.Count > 0)
            return source.Last();

        else return default(PropertyVersion<TValue, TVersion>);
    }
}

public class TrackedPropertyToValueConverter<TValue, TVersion> : ITypeConverter<TrackedProperty<TValue, TVersion>, TValue>
{
    public TValue Convert(TrackedProperty<TValue, TVersion> source, TValue destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var vers = context.Mapper.Map(source, typeof(TrackedProperty<TValue, TVersion>), typeof(PropertyVersion<TValue,TVersion>));
        return (TValue)context.Mapper.Map(vers, typeof(PropertyVersion<TValue, TVersion>), typeof(TValue));
    }
}
```

The first mapping line extracts PropertyVersion.Value.

The second mapping line assumes I need only the last version in TrackedProperty and extracts that one.

The third line brings everything together.

I could probably combine everything into one and have one CreateMap line and one Converter but that's trivial.

Comment: I was thinking for something like this (what you mentioned at the end), but didn't realize you can use `typeof(object)` as destination type. +1 P.S. You may consider accepting your own answer so the people know the issue is resolved.

Comment: @IvanStoev I cannot accept it yet (until tomorrow). Having this issue resolved, I need to work on mapping between TrackedEntity (which can have normal properties + tracked properties) and Entity (only normal properties) types. Since the number and the name of the properties will always be the same (by design), do you think there is any benefit in terms of performance if I discard AutoMapper completely and use Reflection?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. One of the benefits of using AM is that it caches (and compiles) almost everything, so theoretically it should provide better performance than reflection.

Comment: That's an interesting way of resolving it, I tried using `typeof(string)` which didn't work, but I've never thought using `typeof(object)`, I thought it would fail as well. About the performance, I don't think you're going to havy a significant performance loss with this, unless you are really converting a massive number of objects. Nice to know you found a better solution, I added to favorites, it might help me one day. I also liked your way of versionating property values, very smart. Also upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to map `Foo` to `TrackedFoo`, since they have the same property names, at first everything will be fine. Problem arises when AutoMapper tries to convert the property **Name** (`string`) of your `Foo` to a a property **Name** (`TrackedProperty<string,DateTime>`) of your `TrackedFoo`.

Since AutoMapper doesn't know how to natevely convert between `string` and `TrackedProperty<,>`, it will fail.

Though, you can teach AutoMapper how to convert between these types. For this, you need a [Custom Type Converter](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters):

```
public class TrackedPropertyConverter<TValue, TVersion> : ITypeConverter<TrackedProperty<TValue, TVersion>, TValue>
{
    public TValue Convert(TrackedProperty<TValue, TVersion> source, TValue destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source.First().Value;
    }
}
```

Then you configure it like this:

```
  Mapper.Initialize(
            cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<TrackedFoo, Foo>();

                cfg.CreateMap<TrackedProperty<string, DateTime>, string>().ConvertUsing<TrackedPropertyConverter<string,DateTime>>();
                cfg.CreateMap<TrackedProperty<int, DateTime>, int>().ConvertUsing<TrackedPropertyConverter<int, DateTime>>();
                cfg.CreateMap<TrackedProperty<double, DateTime>, double>().ConvertUsing<TrackedPropertyConverter<double, DateTime>>();
            }
        );

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

And here is a sample usage:

```
var tracked = new TrackedFoo
{
    Id = "SomeGuid",
    Name = new TrackedProperty<string, DateTime> {
        new PropertyVersion<string, DateTime> { Value = "FooBar", Version = new DateTime(2017, 2, 28) }
    },
    Value = new TrackedProperty<int, DateTime> {
        new PropertyVersion<int, DateTime> { Value = 456, Version = new DateTime(2017, 2, 28) }
    }
};

var foo = Mapper.Map<Foo>(tracked);

Console.WriteLine("Id: {0} | Name: {1} | Value: {2}", foo.Id, foo.Name, foo.Value);
Console.ReadLine();
```

This is a generic way of teaching AutoMapper how to convert between types, no matter what objects with these types are being converted (e.g Foo to TrackedFoo / Bar to TrackedBar / Person to TrackedPerson).

You must **explicitly configure each type** (string, int, double), like the example in their page, but you just do it once, you don't have to do it for all possible classes using tracked properties.

Also, your repository is responsible for taking a version value as parameter (like a `DateTime`), and getting the `TrackedProperty` with the single value you asked for that version, since you can't have multiple values for the same version.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but there is nothing generic about your answer. You just created configuration per concrete type.

Comment: @Zagoda I edited my answer. I can't figure out something more generic than this, or maybe I misunderstood what you really want. Even though `TrackedProperty` is a list, when getting a `TrackedFoo´ from database, you should only populate this list with a single item, containing the value of the version you want.

Comment: @Zagoda another thing is valid to comment. It's possible to use `CreateMap(typeof(SomethingWithOneGenericType<>), typeof(TrackedProperty<,>))` where your `TrackedProperty` has two generic types (take note the comma in `<,>`). But both types must use generics, therefore you can't use use `typeof(string)` and `typeof(TrackedProperty<,>)`. If this is what you wanted, AutoMapper doesn't support (idk why). The solution I proposed is the most dynamic I could find.

Answer (score -1):

The whole idea of the automapper is to map specific object between each other.
When we worked with generics we created a helper function:

```
public static class AutoMaps
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            CreateGenericMapping<CatModel>(cfg);
        });
    }
    public static void CreateCatMapping<TCatType>(IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg)
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<TCatType, Cat>();
        cfg.CreateMap<Cat, TCatType>();
    }
}
```